# Complex WHERE condition in Android cursor query

Tags: java, android, cursor, where-clause

I want to query the Contacts data and retrieve a contact name and a phone number with the following condition: if a contact has a mobile number then pick that number, else pick any number/first number the contact has. Is it possible to formulate this condition in a cursor query or would I have to do it within a custom cursor adapter?

This is the code I have at the moment. It works fine but it retrieves all numbers for all contacts, therefore I get duplicate names if a person has more than one contact.

```
private String WHERE_CONDITION = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" +
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
private String[] PROJECTION = {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, ContactsContract.Data._ID };
private String SORT_ORDER = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME;
cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(
ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, WHERE_CONDITION, null, SORT_ORDER);
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Apologies, wrongfully tagged as javascript. Now changed to Java.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier and simpler to put this logic in Java. Just retrieve all numbers and select the one you need. Typically you will have at most 3 numbers, may be 5. In any case overhead will be very low.

Comment: Sorry, see my comment above. Changed the tag to Java.